# Does find my iPhone store history

Tags: find-my-iphone

I know the location of my iPhone. However, I want to know the history of where the iPhone has been.

My iPhone is stolen. I turned off the sim card. Which was a big mistake. Now I can no longer track the phone.

I wish I knew where the phone had been?

The only time the phone will show that it's lost is if it connects to internet. The thing is there is no free wifi in Indonesia and the simcard there is disabled. So the only time it'll connect to internet is when some possibly not so innocent buyer connect it.

Answer (score 1):

No, if you did not enable lost mode, the device's location history is not recorded.

Comment: If I enable lost mode the location history will be recorded? Awesome. I did it late unfortunately.

Comment: @Jim Yes, lost mode shows a history of the location of the device whilst lost mode was enabled.